# How i can parse the first information in to CSV?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to parse more than 100 json files, but i do not need all the info.
i only need to parse the first set of the 'coordinates', the CSV already have printed URL and URL type, but i cannot print the first set of coordinates.

this is a section of the Json file

```
{
  "type":"featureCollection",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type": "feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "multilinestring",
        "coordinates":[
          [
            [
              148.9395348,
              -21.3292286
            ],
               [
              148.93963,
              -21.33001
            ],
            [
              148.93969,
              -21.3303
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties":{
       "url" :"www.thiswebpageisfake.com",
       "url_type":"fake"
      },
      "information":{
        "timestamp":"10/10/19"
      }
    }]
}
```

i'm  using python 2.7, i have tried creating an array for coordinates but i have a type error

```
import os
import csv
import json
import sys

reload(sys)

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Python\\json'
dirs = os.listdir(file_path)
file_out = 'C:\\Users\\user\\output.csv'
f = csv.writer(open(file_out, "wb+"))
f.writerow(
    ['url','url_type','lat','long'])

for file in dirs:
    json_dict = json.loads(open(os.path.join(file_path, file)).read())
    print file

for key in json_dict['features']:
    for key1 in key:
        description = key['properties']['description']
        if description is None:
            description = 'null'

        array = ()
        array = (key['geometry']['type']['coordinates'])

        f.writerow([file,                                       
                    key['properties']['url'],                    
                    key['properties']['url_type'],     
                    array[1]                                                               
                    ])
print 'completed'
```

Comment: Will you please paste the full trace of error in your question?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/j13sanch/PycharmProjects/jsontocsv_new_zeland/queenslandjson.py", line 28, in <module>
   array = (key['geometry']['type']['coordinates'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like your second loop is supposed to be nested in the first, otherwise you'll do nothing with all json files except the last and only end up processing one file.

Secondly, your array should be defined as `array = (key['geometry']['coordinates'])`, as `'coordinates'` is not contained in `'type'`.

Comment: the loop is nested, and Coordinates is inside of `'type'`, if i try `array = (key['geometry']['coordinates'])`  a key erros shows up.

Comment: Add `print(key['geometry']['coordinates'])` to your code and see if it prints out what you want. `'Coordinates'` is definitely not inside `'type'`.